# SSAS: Impersonation access (Service access)

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

I am Using Visual Studio Data Tool and trying to create a SSAS project so I created data source and use my SQL Authentication to access the Data source
and i choose the service access as impersonation access to deploy the cube

I have got this error when i deployed the cube

> Error  6   OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.      0   0

I checked the SQL Management studio and I didn't find the service account for Analysis services which is **NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService** only i found a user named **MSSQLServerOLAPService** then i added new user in SQL Data Base named **NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService** and i have deployed the cube but i got the same error message.

Comment: Your admin can verify if the SSAS instance has added your domain/user account to be able to LOGIN. Note this is entirely separate from a USER account. Login gets you in the door, but the user account gets the keys.

Comment: Dear it works check my comment sincerely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have found the solution it is more easy than what i expected.
the service account is not granted to read from the data base
so i opened SQL Management studio and changed to privilege of the account to be **db_datareader** and it works fine.

Comment: Exactly. I actually had this trouble a few months ago myself. Also, you can select your own answer as a solution to your post. Happy coding! Regards,